# Amazon RDS freezes on mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, aws, amazon-rds

My questions is quite similar to [Mysqldump from the Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38826/mysqldump-from-the-amazon-rds). I have the same behavior. Everytime when I do a backup using mysqldump my entire RDS freezes and hence my application is not responding. I am using --single-transaction with the mysqldump command but that doesn't help at all. With this, RDS is quite unusable since I can not dump a backup or data sample during live operation. Is there a way to get the data out of RDS without freezing everything?

Comment: Have you looked at `processlist` while the DB is dumping? There could be locked MyISAM tables causing queue of statements waiting for locks to be released.

Comment: That was a great hint! Thanks, it helped me finding out, that in the deepness of my fab management scripts there was still one mysqldump command without the `--single-transaction` which locked the tables for write access. It would be great if you could write your hint as the answer so I can close the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at processlist while the DB is dumping. There could be locked MyISAM tables causing queue of statements waiting for locks to be released.